# Python queue keep only the latest element with specific condition

Tags: python, queue

Let's say in the traditional producer/consumer pattern, the producer will produce two types of elements, `A` & `B`. The buffer queue should implement the following logics:

- Thread safe.
- FIFO
- All `A` can safely stay in the queue, which denote **important** task.
- Whenever a new `B` arrive, kick out all preceeding `B` in the queue and append to the end of the queue, which denote the **latest** non-important task.
- The order of elements should be preserved.
- The consumer pop element just like normal.

For simplicity, just imagine the size of the queue is unlimited.
Is it possible to implement this without using 2 queues?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, here *all* makes no sense: *"Whenever a new B arrive, kick out all preceeding B in the queue and append to the end of the queue, which denote the latest non-important task."* According to this logic there should only ever be a single "B" in the queue.

Comment: @NotAName Yes, the queue should only have 1 or 0 `B`, keep the latest, or be consumed.

Comment: *"Is it possible to implement this without using 2 queues?"* - How about using **3** queues? :-) Why does the number of queues matter and what solution do you have in mind with 2 queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably subclass a `collections.deque` and get something like:

```
from collection import deque 

class Foo(deque[str]):
    def append(self, val: str):
        if val == 'A':
            super().append(val)
        else:
            try:
                while True:
                    super().remove('B')
            except ValueError:
                pass
            super().append(val)
```

*Note:* `while True` block is here in case you initialise the queue from an iterable and there's more than 1 'B' to begin with, because nothing stops you from doing this: `q = Foo(['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])`. If you wanted to, you can also ovverride the parent's `__init __` to make sure there's always only 1 `'B'` in the queue.

And then you can keep putting tasks in the queue:

```
tasks = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']
q = Foo()
for i in tasks:
    q.append(i)
    print(q)

Out:
Foo(['A'])
Foo(['A', 'A'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'])
Foo(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'])
```

Finally, you use `popleft()` to get elements in FIFO order.

`deque` also should be thread-safe: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: "Finally, you use `pop` to get elements in FIFO order." Using `pop` would result in a LIFO order.

Comment: @blhsing, sorry, my bad. Should use `popleft()` here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to evict the B's from the queue, it's probably simplest to just check as you pop off a B to see if it's the only one in the queue.

```
queue = deque()

def push(x):
    queue.append(x)

def pop(x):
    while True:
       result = queue.popleft()
       if result == 'B' and 'B' in queue:
            continue
    return result
```

With a little bit more effort, you can keep count of the number of B's on the queue, and only process the B when the count goes down to 0.  This will save the cost of `'B' in queue` but the count will have to be accessed via a lock to be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach to kicking out an existing unimportant task from a potentially long queue of tasks would be to use a doubly linked list as a queue, and maintain a reference to the node of the unimportant task, if any, so that the referenced node can be removed in an *O(1)* time complexity.

Using [`llist.dllist`](https://ajakubek.github.io/python-llist/index.html#llist.dllist), an excellent implementation of doubly linked list from the [`llist`](https://pypi.org/project/llist/#:%7E:text=llist%20is%20an%20extension%20module,be%20significantly%20faster%20than%20collections.) module:

```
from llist import dllist
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Task:
    name: str

class UnimportantTask(Task):
    pass

class Tasks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = dllist()
        self.unimportant_task = None

    def add(self, task):
        node = self.queue.appendright(task)
        if isinstance(task, UnimportantTask):
            if self.unimportant_task:
                self.queue.remove(self.unimportant_task)
            self.unimportant_task = node

    def next(self):
        if self.queue:
            task = self.queue.popleft()
            if isinstance(task, UnimportantTask):
                self.unimportant_task = None
            return task
```

so that:

```
tasks = Tasks()
tasks.add(Task('A1'))
tasks.add(Task('A2'))
tasks.add(UnimportantTask('B1'))
tasks.add(Task('A3'))
tasks.add(UnimportantTask('B2'))
tasks.add(UnimportantTask('B3'))
tasks.add(Task('A4'))
while task := tasks.next():
    print(task)
```

outputs:

```
Task(name='A1')
Task(name='A2')
Task(name='A3')
UnimportantTask(name='B3')
Task(name='A4')
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/UnimportantTaskQueue#main.py